# using promise in http request in angular

Tags: angularjs

the problem is when I use $http or $resource to retrieve data, it is successfully retrieve and bind to view, but when I use promise the data come to client but it does not bind to the view.
here is my code:
//view

```
<div class="pull-left span6" >

<h3>{{Name}}</h3>

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="type in typeList">
        <span>{{type.Title}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

//controller

```
var proxyControllers = angular.module('httpProxyControllers', []);

proxyControllers.controller('TypeListController',
function TypeListController($scope, typeListData) {
    $scope.Name = 'Type List Addresses';
    $scope.typeList = typeListData.getTypeList();

    $scope.typeList.then(function(data){
        console.log('data received');
        console.log(data);
    },function(status){
        console.log(status);
    });
});
```

//service

```
var proxyServices = angular.module('httpProxyServices', ['ngResource']);


proxyServices.factory('typeListData' , function($http, $q){
    return{
        getTypeList : function(){
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http({method : 'GET' , url: '/data/getTypeList'})
                .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                })
                .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
                    deferred.reject(status);
                });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
});
```

in then block of controller when i log data to console, it shows that data comes back successfully but nothing happen to my view and my view shows nothing actually.

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign `data` to `$scope.typeList`

```
//initialize with empty array
$scope.typeList = [];

typeListData.getTypeList().then(function(data){

    //initialize with received data
    $scope.typeList = data;

    console.log('data received');
    console.log(data);
},function(status){
    console.log(status);
});
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your quick reply, your answer is correct. however, if i oblige to set typeList in then block with data received, what is the difference if i send callback method and not to use promise? and as far as I remember i saw in a video toturial that he didn't actually use then method and he mentioned that the promise will be binded to view and in the demonstration it worked fine. thanks again.

Comment: in the tutorial you saw he was probably using $resourse not $http.

Comment: @ali, Sorry was offline for sometime. I agree with @MohammadSepahvand probably you saw using `$resourse` not `$http` as I have never used `$http` as such